# Scraping an image from a url

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to scrape an image from a url. First i tried using a simple img, however it kept returning:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
```

Then i tried to embed in a iframe, but that returned

```
Refused to display 'http://www.gosugamers.net//uploads/images/teams/10649-1422301535.jpeg' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

I guess this is due to the fact that this website has disallowed hotlinking images, however how come it then works in jsfiddle?

http://jsfiddle.net/2LExA/17/

Comment: The image is probably in your browser's cache so it looks like it works in jsfiddle when it's actually retrieving it from the cache. Clear the cache or try it with another browser.

Comment: Strange now it either does not work for me... Is it possible to scrape a image even though the page disallow it.

Comment: Christian, your code works fine. You made a mistake in the URL. You have to get rid of the // and change it to one single /. Also, you don't have to load the image twice. Delete the second img load and just keep the iframe.

Comment: i've updated and still does not seem to work
http://jsfiddle.net/2LExA/18/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hotlink to image even though its prevented](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28997162/hotlink-to-image-even-though-its-prevented)

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me [screenshot](http://s30.postimg.org/r0wim9oe9/screen_shot.png). If your still having trouble you can always upload the image to a website and use the new URL.

Comment: I uploaded it to another URL. Try `<img src="http://s27.postimg.org/ng58h5z1b/10649_1422301535.jpg">` If that still doesn't work try clearing your cache or using a different browser.

Comment: That works, however i'm retrieving the above path dynamically, so it is not possible for me to upload it to another url. Only if you can do it programitically.

Comment: Did you try another browser?